# Oracle SQL check if a set of specific values exist in a partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out a way to flag a group of rows as SUCCESS if all the three values (BOL, INV and PER) below exist in a partition. 14RTGZ is a failure because BOL is missing. PERMIT_NO should only contain BOL, INV and PER else it's a failure.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

| PERMIT_NO | DOC_TYP | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14RTGJ | BOL | SUCCESS |
| 14RTGJ | INV | SUCCESS |
| 14RTGJ | PER | SUCCESS |
| 14RTGZ | AWB | FAILURE |
| 14RTGZ | INV | FAILURE |
| 14RTGZ | PER | FAILURE |

So far, I tried the below logic but it doesn't seem to work.

```
MAX(CASE WHEN DOC_TYP = 'BOL' AND DOC_TYP = 'INV' AND DOC_TYP = 'PER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PERMIT_NO) as condition
```

Comment: What do you expect your `CASE` to achieve?

Comment: If DOC_TYP contains all three values BOL, INV and PER for a specific Permit Number, then the flag should be SUCCESS. But I am hoping it should be AND instead of OR but still the logic does not work.

Comment: Which part of your code implements "*all three values*" part?

Comment: CASE WHEN DOC_TYP = 'BOL' OR DOC_TYP = 'INV' OR DOC_TYP = 'PER' checks if all the values are available within the partition.

Comment: No, the condition checks if there at least **one** value from the three.

Comment: Correct, in one my previous comments I corrected it to be AND condition so all the three values are considered. I also tried using AND condition but it flags failure where Success if expected.

Comment: You can not use `AND` in your code (as written) since it's evaluated on **row** basis.

Comment: Got it. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Yes, have three separate variables to count each DOC_TYP individually and then check that each of them equals 1.  That assumes that as long as you have all the three values it does not matter if some other values are present as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT`, `DISTINCT` and `CASE` to count how many of your desired values exist in the partition. If that count is `3`, the row is flagged as `SUCCESS`.

```
SELECT permit_no, doc_typ,
       CASE WHEN ( COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN doc_typ IN ( 'BOL', 'INV', 'PER' )
                                        THEN doc_typ
                                   END
                 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY permit_no ) = 3 )
            THEN 'SUCCESS' ELSE 'FAILURE'
       END AS flag
FROM permits;
```

| permit_no | doc_typ | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14RTGJ | BOL | SUCCESS |
| 14RTGJ | INV | SUCCESS |
| 14RTGJ | PER | SUCCESS |
| 14RTGZ | INV | FAILURE |
| 14RTGZ | PER | FAILURE |
| 14RTGZ | AWB | FAILURE |

Comment: This works for multiple DOC_TYP combinations. Awesome! Thanks Peter!

Comment: @Onkar This will only check if all 3 required `doc_typ` are present it will not check whether any other `doc_typ` are also present. If you have the requirement "PERMIT_NO should only contain BOL, INV and PER else it's a failure" then you also need to check the other values in the table that do not match the required `doc_typ`s and count to see that they are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation and check for each condition and also check for non-instances of the negation of the condition:

```sql
SELECT permit_no,
       doc_typ,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(CASE doc_typ WHEN 'BOL' THEN 1 END)
              OVER (PARTITION BY permit_no) > 0
       AND  COUNT(CASE doc_typ WHEN 'INV' THEN 1 END)
              OVER (PARTITION BY permit_no) > 0
       AND  COUNT(CASE doc_typ WHEN 'PER' THEN 1 END)
              OVER (PARTITION BY permit_no) > 0
       AND  COUNT(CASE WHEN doc_typ IN ('BOL', 'PER', 'INV') THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)
              OVER (PARTITION BY permit_no) = 0
       THEN 'SUCCESS'
       ELSE 'FALIURE'
       END AS flag
FROM   table_name;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT permit_no,
       doc_typ,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN doc_typ IN ('BOL', 'INV', 'PER') THEN doc_typ END)
              OVER (PARTITION BY permit_no) = 3
       AND  COUNT(DISTINCT doc_typ)
              OVER (PARTITION BY permit_no) = 3
       THEN 'SUCCESS'
       ELSE 'FALIURE'
       END AS flag
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (PERMIT_NO, DOC_TYP) AS
SELECT '14RTGJ', 'BOL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14RTGJ', 'INV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14RTGJ', 'PER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14RTGZ', 'AWB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14RTGZ', 'INV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14RTGZ', 'PER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14RTGX', 'AWB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14RTGX', 'BOL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14RTGX', 'INV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14RTGX', 'PER' FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

| PERMIT_NO | DOC_TYP | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14RTGJ | PER | SUCCESS |
| 14RTGJ | BOL | SUCCESS |
| 14RTGJ | INV | SUCCESS |
| 14RTGX | INV | FALIURE |
| 14RTGX | BOL | FALIURE |
| 14RTGX | PER | FALIURE |
| 14RTGX | AWB | FALIURE |
| 14RTGZ | PER | FALIURE |
| 14RTGZ | AWB | FALIURE |
| 14RTGZ | INV | FALIURE |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rsKeB7dO)